# Using an if else statement with numpy for Arithmetic calculations

Tags: python, numpy, slice, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I want to do a `numpy.where()` statement where if the length of the `PC_list` is equal to the length of the numbers then I want the standard deviation to be calculated of the `PC_list[0:number].std()` and also I want to delete the first number in `PC_list`: `np.setdiff1d(PC_list,PC_list[0])`. I want this process to go on until the list number is not equal to number `len(PC_list[0:number]!=number`. I tried to format `numpy.where()` that way however I get a syntax error when done that, so I need a correction on the `numpy.where()` function below.

Code:

```
number = 3
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
np.where(len(PC_list[0:number]==number,default = 'NA', PC_list[0:number].std(), np.setdiff1d(PC_list,PC_list[0])))
```

Vanilla Python Code:

```
from copy import deepcopy
list_ = deepcopy(PC_list)
if len(list_[0:number]==number:
   STD = list_[0:number].std()
   list_ = np.setdiff1d(list_,list_[0])
```

Error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-93-215f70228bdc>", line 1
    np.where(len(PC_list[0:number]==number,default = 'NA', PC_list[0:number].std(), np.setdiff1d(PC_list,PC_list[0])))
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: `where` takes 3 arguments, `cond` and `a` and `b`.  In complex cases you should create those one separate lines.  That's way they'll be easier to read and debug.

Comment: alalways put full error message (starting at word "Tracebak") in question (not commet) as text (not screeshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: it seems like you have all in one `len()` and you have something missing between `default = 'NA'` and `PC_list[0:number].std()`. Maybe put code in functions and make it simpler `where(filter(), func1, func2)`

Comment: @hpaulj I added the error message also updated the code as the vanilla python version.

Comment: did you try closing the parenthesis for `len(PC_list[0:number]==number,`

Comment: @anurag I have done that, yea sorry was a foolish mistake

Comment: In that case try placing this `default = 'NA'` argument at the end of the function, bcz defaults must come **after** positional arguments!

Comment: @anurag I get an invalid syntax error, can I have 2 options for the formatting, I want to calculate the standard deviation `PC_list[0:number].std()` and then delete the first index in the list `np.setdiff1d(PC_list,PC_list[0])`: the entire function : `np.where(len(PC_list[0:number])!=number,PC_list[0:number].std()np.setdiff1d(PC_list,PC_list[0]), default = 'NA')`